# Fixing vertices that have been deleted or moved

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

What is the easiest way of returning a vertice to its original location if it has been  moved out of place (without using undo) and replacing a deleted vertice (again without using undo)?

I have included a file maybe it will help if someone takes the time to answer.  Thank you to anyone who does.

[image]

Comment: the short answer is: you can't. That's why you are making (hopefully) copies of every important step of your creation. Only in very special cases you can return to original location e.g. you had a circle before or some other "easy" cases. If you have such a special case, you should describe it more in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the misplaced or missing geometry bears a logical relationship to the remaining parts, there's nearly always a way.

In both illustrations here, Snap is set 'To: Vertex' and 'With: Active', affecting Move, Rotate, and Scale. Personally I have that setting in my start-up file.. I find it's by far the most common.

In your first case, the moved vertex should return to the average position of the adjacent vertices in the loop. Blender's Snap  provides for that, with the <kbd>A</kbd> key:

[image]

With Snap set ON, locate over the first target to be averaged, tap <kbd>A</kbd>, hover over the second target, and left-click. Done.

In your second case, you can make a patch from adjacent faces, snap-rotate them into place, and <kbd>M</kbd> merge by distance. For speed in the gif, here, Header > Options > 'Automerge' is checked, to make the manual <kbd>M</kbd> weld unnecessary...

[image]

First the centre of rotation has to be in the right place; the Pivot is set to '3D Cursor', and the 3D cursor is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> put somewhere on the rotational axis of your bolt-object. The axis of rotation is Global Y.

Select the patch in Face mode, switch to Vertex mode so you can make a source vertex active, and rotate a copy of that region to the target with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> .

Comment: For replacing patches in arbitrarily curved surfaces, take a look at Ian McGlasham's 'Panel Beating' [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goJ4LVHXkC4) , on the use of the shipped add-on 'Loop Tools' > Curve option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to fix my mistake with the answer you provided! With your response and the other response that was provided I was able to fix the issue.  Also I learned 2 new ways of doing things!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer and share your knowledge! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can't but in your case you can easily fix the topology. First thing delete the vertex:

[image]

Select the opposite edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to fix my mistake with the answer you provided! It was a little bit different than the example that I had provided.  I should have just sent the actual file I was working on but I started a new file as I was messing around trying to figure it out myself before I asked for help.  Thanks again.